# Can't enable "Advanced Threat Defense" BitDefender's feature

Tags: windows-10, bitdefender

I can't enable BitDefender's "Advanced Threat Defense" - the slider just slides back to "off" state no matter what I do.

Prior to BitDef I was using Malwarebytes but I uninstalled it using a cleaning tool that was created by the producer.

Sys specs: 
- Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1803, build 17134.81),
- BitDefender Total Security 2018 (30 Day Free Trial)

I tried to: 
- Reinstall BitDef.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you contact BitDefender support?

Comment: @FleetCommand Yes, I tried to send them a ticket but I didn't get any email confirmation that they got it, so I assumed it was unsuccessful.

Comment: "Advanced Threat Defense" is a service. You pay them monthly for it, so if it is not working, you should take some drastic steps to either contact them or get your money back. (Of course, since it is your money, technically, you are allowed to do what you please with it. I am just saying... 'cause most people care about getting their money's worth.)

Comment: @FleetCommand Sorry, where did You find that "Advanced Threat Defense" is a service?

Right now I have opened a 30-day trial account. it was explicitly said that trial account gives me access to all features so I assumed there was some sort of software/privileges/etc conflict. But I might be mistaken - right now I just want to learn more - perhaps it's how it should have been.

Comment: A BitDefender representative came and advertised+educated us... Of course, you are saying it is a trial, so, I'll just stop talking here.

Comment: There is no need to... I came here hoping that I will find someone who will be able to help me. If you can think of any solution to my problem keep talking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to reach Bitdefender's support (sending tickets from the Bitdefender antivirus program does not work - I had to contact them through 24/7 online chat).

Here is the response:

> Hi **,
>
> Thank you for your patience throughout this entire process and please accept my apologies for the frustration that we might have caused.
>
> Our developers analyzed the case and it seems that Hypervisor Code Integrity (HVCI) is responsible for the Advanced Threat Defense malfunction. They are currently working on a fix which will be done by means of an automatic update.
>
> In the meantime, as a workaround please try to disable Device Guard by following the steps 1-5 and 7 from this article:
>   https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/68913-enable-disable-device-guard-windows-10-a.html
>
> We will contact you again as soon as we have news about the release date. Thank you for your patience and understanding.
>
> Have a nice day ahead!
>
> Cordially,
>
> **
>   Senior Technical Support Engineer

Workaround solved my problem.

Comment: Two years later, problem persists.